# Issues running 'ddply' command of plyr R library

Tags: r, plyr

I have some newbie question for confirmed R users :-). I have an object of class "loci" with rows corresponding to individuals, and columns corresponding to genotypes at different SNP loci (+ 1 column for population information):

`gen.loc
Allelic data frame: 283 individuals
                    151 loci
                    1 additional variable`

as.data.frame(gen.loc)
    population PBA10091 PBA10106 PBA10242 PBA10272 PBA11037 PBA11455 PBA11744 
001       ANTE    01/02    01/01    01/01    02/02    02/02    02/02    01/01
002       ANTE    01/01    01/01    01/01    02/02    01/02    02/02    01/02
003       ANTE    01/01    02/02    01/01    02/02    02/02    01/02    01/01
004       ANTE    01/01    01/01    01/01    02/02    02/02    01/02    01/01
005       ANTE    01/02    02/02    01/01    02/02    02/02    02/02    01/02
006       ANTE    01/01    02/02    01/02    01/02    01/02    02/02    01/01

I have 12 populations that are defined in my "population" column. I would like to calculate pairwise genotypic distance between individuals within each population.

With just one pop, the command would be:

`d <- dist.gene(gen.loc, method="pairwise", pairwise.deletion = TRUE, variance = FALSE)`

It returns an object of class 'dist' with pairwise differences between individuals.

However, I would like to split my dataframe according to the 12 levels of the "population" columns, and factorize this procedure using an 'apply' function.

I tried the 'ddply' function of the *plyr* library:

`ddply(as.data.frame(gen.loc), as.data.frame(gen.loc)$population, function(e) dist.gene(e, method="pairwise", pairwise.deletion = TRUE, variance = FALSE))`

Unfortunately this command returns an error message:

`Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'ANTE' not found`

'ANTE' being the first pop that appears in the dataframe, I guess the splitting gone wrong somehow. Also, I guess than there could be an issue with the fact the *dist.gene* outcome is a 'dist' object and not an actual R dataframe.

Is there a better way to use ddply here? Or another approach to split my dataframe while applying the *dist.gene* command? Otherwise I guess I will just be creating one input dataframe per pop... :-) Not convenient if one has a large number of pops though!!

Thanks for any help!

All the best,

Chrys

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try?

```
df <- as.data.frame(gen.loc)
split.df <- split(df, df$population)  # split data frame into list by distinct population
result <- lapply(split.df, function(i) dist.gene(i, method="pairwise", pairwise.deletion = TRUE, variance = FALSE))  # iterate through list and calculate pairwise distance
```